# Cant Get UserID in AcessToken Response with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

In Facebook Javascript SDK when I use:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
            //code here
}
```

I can acess userID "response.authResponse.userID", but when I use Facebook C# SDK the method `oAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(code)` only return AcessToken and Expires and I must make one more call to get this info.

How can I get userID without making one more call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make one more request to get the user id from the access token which is a safer route.

if you do want to get without making a call, refer to this post instead.

[How to get the Facebook user id using the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546677/how-to-get-the-facebook-user-id-using-the-access-token/4614193#4614193)

Comment: thanks for quick response, but I cant understand why my acesstoken is not like "1249203702|2.h1MTNeLqcLqw__.86400.129394400-605430316|-WE1iH_CV-afTgyhDPc" but is more like this: "AAADOFHuZBFNcBABE6gCrlKkaox94dkFDVg0DBaZBPdzAnhN3sS3oh9nAm7toH2SZAMoXH1e14fWBAJVRQ1XT0iIVTirhaONDJhVwwplBeKsZCRKYku1P" in my javascript code (with oauth=true) I can get UserId, Expires, SignedRequest, Status etc... but I cant do this in Facebook SDK without use Get("/me").