# HTTP GET Request in Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest

How can I make an HTTP request from within Node.js or Express.js? I need to connect to another service. I am hoping the call is asynchronous and that the callback contains the remote server's response.

Comment: In Node.js 18, the fetch API is available on the global scope by default

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-is-an-http-post-request-made-in-node-js/71991867#71991867

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Here is a snippet of some code from a sample of mine. It's asynchronous and returns a JSON object.  It can do any form of GET request.

Note that there are more optimal ways (just a sample) - for example, instead of concatenating the chunks you put into an array and join it etc... Hopefully, it gets you started in the right direction:

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

/**
 * getJSON:  RESTful GET request returning JSON object(s)
 * @param options: http options object
 * @param callback: callback to pass the results JSON object(s) back
 */

module.exports.getJSON = (options, onResult) => {
  console.log('rest::getJSON');
  const port = options.port == 443 ? https : http;

  let output = '';

  const req = port.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`${options.host} : ${res.statusCode}`);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      output += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      let obj = JSON.parse(output);

      onResult(res.statusCode, obj);
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (err) => {
    // res.send('error: ' + err.message);
  });

  req.end();
};
```

It's called by creating an options object like:

```
const options = {
  host: 'somesite.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/some/path',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

And providing a callback function.

For example, in a service, I require the REST module above and then do this:

```
rest.getJSON(options, (statusCode, result) => {
  // I could work with the resulting HTML/JSON here. I could also just return it
  console.log(`onResult: (${statusCode})\n\n${JSON.stringify(result)}`);

  res.statusCode = statusCode;

  res.send(result);
});
```

### UPDATE

If you're looking for `async`/`await` (linear, no callback), promises, compile time support and intellisense, we created a lightweight HTTP and REST client that fits that bill:

[Microsoft typed-rest-client](https://github.com/Microsoft/typed-rest-client)

Comment: @bryanmac can you please send/add the complete sample?

Comment: @bryanmac with your permission I would like to use this code grunt plugin i'm currently building. Not sure when but it would be made open sourced when completed.

Comment: @JeffH - no problem.  no rocket science here, standard http calls :)

Comment: try request module .. it is much simpler http://www.sitepoint.com/making-http-requests-in-node-js/

Comment: yes - request module is simple but this is lower level showing what libraries like request module is doing.  If you need lower level control or http requests (showing progress on large downloads etc...), this shows how it's done.

Comment: @bryanmac Could you please provide the detailed documentation link about available options? searched for `joyent node https module`, but, not found!

Comment: Is it this one? https://github.com/joyent/node-http-signature I was trying to figure out is there any other options for specifying query params, or just add the big string in `path`.

Comment: @KrIsHnA - node has a querystring object: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html and url object https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html

Comment: Cool, but why is node_modules part of the repo!?

Comment: I'm trying to run this code but I keep getting the error  `res` is undefined when inside of my `onResult` call.

Comment: How did you 'require' the module?

Comment: would you please tell me what in onResult and how it works?

Answer (score 109):

Try using the simple [`http.get(options, callback)` function](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) in node.js:

```javascript
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  path: '/index.html'
};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  // Buffer the body entirely for processing as a whole.
  var bodyChunks = [];
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // You can process streamed parts here...
    bodyChunks.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
    console.log('BODY: ' + body);
    // ...and/or process the entire body here.
  })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});
```

There is also a general [`http.request(options, callback)` function](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) which allows you to specify the request method and other request details.

Comment: Where's the content of the server's response that the OP asked for?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like there's a need for an 'end' handler to concatenate the chunks then. Which basically amounts to @bryanmac's answer?

Comment: @DanDascalescu: ya, if you want to process the body as a whole (which is likely) then you probably want to buffer it and process on 'end'.  I'll update my answer too for completeness.

Comment: sorry, i can't figure out what parameters callback is called with...how can i get body and where is the reference for parameters and properties of that parameters.

Comment: @maerics How can I use this `GET` request if I have this url? `graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
     input_token={token-to-inspect}
     &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}` ?

Comment: What constraints compelled the Node team to choose not to include a convenience for concatenating the body? Nearly every https request snippet on the web contains a variation of this cumbersome concatenation, many of which are broken, inefficient or otherwise less-than-optimal.

Answer (score 73):

[Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) and [Superagent](http://visionmedia.github.com/superagent/) are pretty good libraries to use.

*note: request is [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request#deprecated), use at your risk!*

Using `request`:

```
var request=require('request');

request.get('https://someplace',options,function(err,res,body){
  if(err) //TODO: handle err
  if(res.statusCode === 200 ) //etc
  //TODO Do something with response
});
```

Comment: Should it be res.statusCode === 200 in second if ? )

Comment: what is the options variable? just pass undefined one? i doubt it

Comment: npm `request` module is deprecated

Answer (score 37):

You can also use [Requestify](http://ranm8.github.io/requestify), a really cool and very simple HTTP client I wrote for nodeJS + it supports caching.

Just do the following for GET method request:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

requestify.get('http://example.com/api/resource')
  .then(function(response) {
      // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
      response.getBody();
  }
);
```

Comment: "Try this other tool " is not an acceptable response if the existing toolset is sufficient.

Comment: sure it is, another solution is always a good thing

Answer (score 14):

This version is based on the initially proposed by [bryanmac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775184/bryanmac) function which uses promises, better error handling, and is rewritten in ES6.

```js
let http = require("http"),
    https = require("https");

/**
* getJSON:  REST get request returning JSON object(s)
* @param options: http options object
*/
exports.getJSON = function (options) {
    console.log('rest::getJSON');
    let reqHandler = +options.port === 443 ? https : http;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let req = reqHandler.request(options, (res) => {
            let output = '';
            console.log('rest::', options.host + ':' + res.statusCode);
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                output += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    let obj = JSON.parse(output);
                    // console.log('rest::', obj);
                    resolve({
                        statusCode: res.statusCode,
                        data: obj
                    });
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.error('rest::end', err);
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('rest::request', err);
            reject(err);
        });

        req.end();
    });
};
```

As a result you don't have to pass in a callback function, instead getJSON() returns a promise. In the following example the function is used inside of an ExpressJS route handler

```js
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    rest.getJSON({
        host: host,
        path: `/posts/${req.params.id}`,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(({ statusCode, data }) => {
        res.json(data);
    }, (error) => {
        next(error);
    });
});
```

On error it delegates the error to the server error handling middleware.

Comment: Yes,this example is showing how to do it inside an Express `get` route definition, which many posts here are lacking.

Comment: In your 2nd code regarding this `express example`, it seems like it is the server code whereas the first code is client code. What is `rest.getJSON` in 2nd code? Is it a typo and should be `res.getJSON`?

Comment: `rest` is the object that's exported in the first code block. Therefore in order to access `getJSON()` you can either import the entire `rest` object or just import `getJSON` from the first file. They both are server side excerpts.

Answer (score 9):

[Unirest](http://unirest.io/) is the best library I've come across for making HTTP requests from Node.  It's aiming at being a multiplatform framework, so learning how it works on Node will serve you well if you need to use an HTTP client on Ruby, PHP, Java, Python, Objective C, .Net or Windows 8 as well.  As far as I can tell the unirest libraries are mostly backed by existing HTTP clients (e.g. on Java, the Apache HTTP client, on Node, [Mikeal's Request libary](https://github.com/mikeal/request)) - Unirest just puts a nicer API on top.

Here are a couple of code examples for Node.js:

```
var unirest = require('unirest')

// GET a resource
unirest.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
  .query({'foo': 'bar'})
  .query({'stack': 'overflow'})
  .end(function(res) {
    if (res.error) {
      console.log('GET error', res.error)
    } else {
      console.log('GET response', res.body)
    }
  })

// POST a form with an attached file
unirest.post('http://httpbin.org/post')
  .field('foo', 'bar')
  .field('stack', 'overflow')
  .attach('myfile', 'examples.js')
  .end(function(res) {
    if (res.error) {
      console.log('POST error', res.error)
    } else {
      console.log('POST response', res.body)
    }
  })
```

You can jump straight to the Node docs [here](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [shred](https://github.com/spire-io/shred/).  It's a node HTTP client created and maintained by [spire.io](http://www.spire.io/) that handles redirects, sessions, and JSON responses.  It's great for interacting with rest APIs.  See [this blog post](http://blog.amt.in/shred-an-http-client-library-for-nodejs) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [httpreq](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-httpreq): it's a node library I created because I was frustrated there was no simple http GET or POST module out there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who looking for a library to send HTTP requests in NodeJS, [**`axios`**](https://github.com/axios/axios) is also a good choice. It supports Promises :)

**Install (npm)**: `npm install axios`

**Example GET request**:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://google.com')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

[**Github page**](https://github.com/axios/axios)

---

**Update 10/02/2022**

[Node.js integrates **fetch** in v17.5.0 in experimental mode](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V17.md#17.5.0). Now, you can use **fetch** to send requests just like you do on the client-side. For now, it is an experimental feature so be careful.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make simple get requests and don't need support for any other HTTP methods take a look at: [simple-get](https://github.com/feross/simple-get):

```
var get = require('simple-get');

get('http://example.com', function (err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(res.statusCode); // 200
  res.pipe(process.stdout); // `res` is a stream
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [reqclient](https://github.com/mrsarm/reqclient): not designed for scripting purpose
like `request` or many other libraries. Reqclient allows in the constructor
specify many configurations useful when you need to reuse the same
configuration again and again: base URL, headers, auth options,
logging options, caching, etc. Also has useful features like
query and URL parsing, automatic query encoding and JSON parsing, etc.

The best way to use the library is create a module to export the object
pointing to the API and the necessary configurations to connect with:

Module `client.js`:

```
let RequestClient = require("reqclient").RequestClient

let client = new RequestClient({
  baseUrl: "https://myapp.com/api/v1",
  cache: true,
  auth: {user: "admin", pass: "secret"}
})

module.exports = client
```

And in the controllers where you need to consume the API use like this:

```
let client = require('client')
//let router = ...

router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  // Simple GET with Promise handling to https://myapp.com/api/v1/reports/clients
  client.get("reports/clients")
    .then(response => {
       console.log("Report for client", response.userId)  // REST responses are parsed as JSON objects
       res.render('clients/dashboard', {title: 'Customer Report', report: response})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("Ups!", err)
      res.status(400).render('error', {error: err})
    })
})

router.get('/orders', (req, res, next) => {
  // GET with query (https://myapp.com/api/v1/orders?state=open&limit=10)
  client.get({"uri": "orders", "query": {"state": "open", "limit": 10}})
    .then(orders => {
      res.render('clients/orders', {title: 'Customer Orders', orders: orders})
    })
    .catch(err => someErrorHandler(req, res, next))
})

router.delete('/orders', (req, res, next) => {
  // DELETE with params (https://myapp.com/api/v1/orders/1234/A987)
  client.delete({
    "uri": "orders/{client}/{id}",
    "params": {"client": "A987", "id": 1234}
  })
  .then(resp => res.status(204))
  .catch(err => someErrorHandler(req, res, next))
})
```

`reqclient` supports many features, but it has some that are not supported by other
libraries: [OAuth2 integration](https://github.com/mrsarm/reqclient#oauth-2-authorization) and logger integration
with [cURL syntax](https://github.com/mrsarm/reqclient#logging-with-curl-style), and always returns native Promise objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to send `GET` request to an `IP` as well as a `Domain` (Other answers did not mention you can specify a `port` variable), you can make use of this function:

```
function getCode(host, port, path, queryString) {
    console.log("(" + host + ":" + port + path + ")" + "Running httpHelper.getCode()")

    // Construct url and query string
    const requestUrl = url.parse(url.format({
        protocol: 'http',
        hostname: host,
        pathname: path,
        port: port,
        query: queryString
    }));

    console.log("(" + host + path + ")" + "Sending GET request")
    // Send request
    console.log(url.format(requestUrl))
    http.get(url.format(requestUrl), (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been received.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log("GET chunk: " + chunk);
            data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
            console.log("GET end of response: " + data);
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("GET Error: " + err);
    });
}
```

Don't miss requiring modules at the top of your file:

```
http = require("http");
url = require('url')
```

Also bare in mind that you may use `https` module for communicating over secured network. so these two lines would change:

```
https = require("https");
...
https.get(url.format(requestUrl), (resp) => { ......
```

Answer (score 0):

In November 2023, the Fetch API graduated to a stable feature in Node.js (Node.js v21 or later). Notice this same code works in this browser too.

```js
const request = new Request("https://api.w3.org/groups");

(async () => {
   let response = await fetch(request);
   for (const entry of response.headers.entries()) {
     console.log(entry[0] + ':' + entry[1]);
   }
   if(response.ok){
      response = await response.json();
      console.log(response)
   } else {
      //do something else
   }
})().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
## you can use request module and promise in express to make any request ##
const promise                       = require('promise');
const requestModule                 = require('request');

const curlRequest =(requestOption) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        requestModule(requestOption, (error, response, body) => {
            try {
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
                if (body) {

                    try {
                        body = (body) ? JSON.parse(body) : body;
                        resolve(body);
                    }catch(error){
                        resolve(body);
                    }

                } else {

                    throw new Error('something wrong');
                }
            } catch (error) {

                reject(error);
            }
        })
    })
};

const option = {
    url : uri,
    method : "GET",
    headers : {

    }
};


curlRequest(option).then((data)=>{
}).catch((err)=>{
})
```

Comment: (As it happens, it won't solve the problem. This code will *listen for a request* but the question is asking how to *send a request*)

Comment: it is fixed, you can try it out. @Quentin