# npm install https

Tags: node.js, express

Hopefully a simple question, 
`npm install http` works fine and I can connect via port 80 to third party services.
`npm install https` by contrast does not latch on to a recognized package

Though I see a reference to package https here:

[HTTP GET Request in Node.js Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express)

What's the `https` analog to package `http` in node.js / Express?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So Node itself has both modules to create a http server and an https server:

- HTTP http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_http
- HTTPS http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_https

Meaning you don't need NPM to get those working, they exist even before NPM itself.

On the other hand NPM will give you access to those great modules/framework.

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a framework based on [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) blabla... it is awesome to make API or Website as long as you are not looking for a full coffee maker framework. There are a few built on top of Express like [railways.js](http://railwayjs.com)

[Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to make HTTP ou HTTPS queries. Request is awesome, it keeps getting better and is today by far the best tool to grab any web content from a node app.
If what you are looking for is to do a scraper you may want to look at [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio).

PS: I took the time to give a good answer. But you should know that the best quality of a developer is to be able to read the docs rather than cry from help without even looking at the doc. My two cents.

Comment: Aha, thanks!  I made a typo which made me think it wasn't finding the package.  Amazing how its hard to see one's one code.  Your answer got me looking close enought.

Comment: Seriously I got a down vote for this answer... sometime I feel like certain person really deserved a big old fashion RTFM.

Comment: Hm, I voted it up and accepted it.  I see it at 2 curently.  I for one greatly appreciate the hint which got me out of temporary blindness.

Comment: And am building in Request, which is elegant. So thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome just a random guy voted it down whatever I know this is not you. Just WTF I feel like I gave the ultimate answer :D Hf with request and use cheerio or jsdom if you ever need to scrap and them you will fall in love with Node.

Comment: Does it make any difference if I use `http` and open the website with `https` (without using https package)?