# Node: Basic JSON request

Tags: json, node.js, request

I'm a complete beginner in Node.js and I wanted to consult something I could not figure out.

Even though I've researched extensively I could not find any method to receive JSON request without using a plugin. I will be using it to program a mobile application API. But even though I've incluede parameter **request** I cannot reach the content by using **request.body**, or **request.data**. The request I'm trying to make is;

```
{
    "id":"123"
}
```

And my failing code is;

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response){
    console.log("Request: "+request.data+"\n");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello, World");
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express/9577651#9577651

Comment: @bryanmac Thanks for the answer. However in your code I could not understand where the "exports" parameter came from?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use express, as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/node-js-extracting-post-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not listening to the `request` events to let you know that you have data, and then parsing the data. You're assuming that `request` has `request.data`.

It should be:

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response){
  var data = '';
  request.setEncoding('utf8');

  // Request received data.
  request.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The end of the request was reached. Handle the data now.
  request.on('end', function() {
    console.log("Request: "+data+"\n");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello, World");
    response.end();
  });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

[See this](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_clientresponse) for the documentation for the methods that `request` contains.