# Refreshing variables after someinterval in Express.js

Tags: json, node.js, express

**How do i fetch values at regular intervals in *Express.js* from an external *json* file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is very vague, but what you can do is setup a function that executes at regular intervals and fetches values from a JSON file.

```
// Fetch values every 3 seconeds
setInterval(function(){

  var fs = require('fs');
  var file = __dirname + '/test.json';

  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    // Now you have a JSON object from which you can extract values.
    // You can save those values somewhere or just log them to the console
    console.dir(data);
  });

}, 3000);
```

Comment: By 'external', I believe OP meant 'remote' json file. If that is the case, replace function in setInterval with similar code in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express