# Make http request to get JSON before express js res.render

Tags: node.js, express

How to make http request(s) to get data from remote server(s) and after that pass requested data as view data in express js?

For example code where view is rendered with static data:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var news = [{id: 1, title: 'News title'}];

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Main page', news: news });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance, using [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request(URL, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.render('index', { title : 'Main page', news : JSON.parse(body) });
  });
});
```

To perform multiple requests, you could use [`async.map()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback):

```
var request = require('request');
var async   = require('async');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var URLS = [ 'http://...', 'http://...', ... ];

  async.map(URLS, function(url, done) {
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return done(err || new Error());
      }
      return done(null, JSON.parse(body));
    });
  }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
    res.render('index', { title : 'Main page', news : results });
  });
});
```

Comment: It works, thx a lot! Is it possible to make multiple request and after they done pass data to res.render? @robertklep