# How to make http.request on "data" handler return Buffers, not strings

Tags: node.js

I am tryint to donwload a binary file via http in nodejs. Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836438/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-with-http-request), I tried this:

```
http.get(url,function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    var body = [];
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        result = Buffer.concat(body);
    });
});
```

The problem is, that the `chunk` data blocks are of type string, not of type buffer. For this reasons `Buffer.concat(body)` fails.

Why and how can I change this?

Comment: This question and answer may be helpful to solving your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35854678/5884189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the "chunks" are of type string is actually because I am calling `setEncoding`. If I remove that line, it works:

```
http.get(url,function (res) {
    //res.setEncoding('binary');
    var body = [];
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        result = Buffer.concat(body);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with using `Buffer` can you use the `Buffer.from()` function.

```
http.get(url,function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    var body = [];
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        result = Buffer.concat(Buffer.from(body));
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "Stick with Buffer"? Do I have other options?

Comment: Treat the result as a string and append on `"data"` then convert to a buffer once you hit `"end"`