# Getting data from restful API in Node (server to server) Node/Express Using Request

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, request

I am trying to connect to TradeGecko API located here:
(all their examples are in ruby - I am using Node)

http://developer.tradegecko.com/

I have a privileged access token that I created
FAKE TOKEN:
146e29b59e7e8861f462101f610f58168ca5edf2f307e5f7adc3314d24ee8015

How can I make a GET request to get all products for example:
http://developer.tradegecko.com/?ruby#list-all-products

The help is much appreciated!

Let say I have some code like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


var testRouter = express.Router();

myRouter.route('/testRoute')
  .get(function(req, res){
    request('API CALL HERE??', function (error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        res.json(body);
      }
    })
  });

app.use('/api', bookRouter);

var myRouter = express.Router();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Welcome to my API');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('GULP is running my app on PORT: ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the end of [the documentation you cited](http://developer.tradegecko.com/?ruby#list-all-products), you will notice that the request is:

```
GET https://api.tradegecko.com/products
```

This is a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API. You need to read about how to provide the access token.

*Typically*, you add a header to your request that says:

> Authorization: Bearer *your token*

...and do a simple GET request.

[Their documentation for authentication](http://developer.tradegecko.com/?ruby#authentication) gives details on how to do the authentication. It is RESTful, so my assumption is correct.

> TradeGecko uses API keys to allow access to the API. You can register
>   a new TradeGecko API key at our developer portal.
>
> TradeGecko expects for the API key to be included in all API requests
>   to the server in a header that looks like the following:
>
> Authorization: Bearer *<ACCESS_TOKEN>*
>
> You must replace  with your personal API key.

This [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577651/1127972) has more details regarding performing REST requests from nodejs.

Got it to work using this: if you would like to add this to your answer for others.

```
myRouter.route('/testRoute')
  .get(function(req, res){
    request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: 'https://api.tradegecko.com/products',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'TOKEN HERE'}
    }, function (error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        res.json(body);
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: Both answers helped me. Thanks got it up and running.

Answer (score 2):

You must send request with ACCESS_TOKEN

```
request({
 url: "",
 method: "",
 headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN},
})
```

Comment: Thanks I got it! Both answers helped me a lot.