# Making external get request with Express

Tags: node.js, express

so I have the following Scenario; I have a private API key that Angular will show in XHR request. To combat this, I decided to use Express as a proxy and make server side requests. However, I cannot seem to find documentation on how to make my own get requests.

Architecture:

Angular makes request to `/api/external-api` --> Express handles the route and makes request to `externalURL` with params in `req.body.params` and attaches API key from `config.apiKey`. The following is pseudocode to imitate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
router.get('/external-api', (req, res) => {
  externalRestGetRequest(externalURL, req.body.params, config.apiKey)
  res.send({ /* get response here */})
}
```

Comment: "send get request with nodejs"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET Request in Node.js Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The accepted answer is good, but in case anyone comes across this question later, let's keep in mind that as of February, 2020, [request](https://github.com/request/request) is now [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142).

So what can we do? We can use another library. I would suggest [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Install it and do something like:

```js
const axios = require('axios')


const url = "https://example.com"

const getData = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    const data = response.data
    console.log(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

getData(url)
```

Answer (score 21):

You are half way there! You need something to make that request for you. Such as the npm library [request](https://github.com/request/request).

In your route something like

```
var request = require('request');


router.get('/external-api', function(req, res){ 

    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
          console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
          console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
          res.send(body)
    });

})
```

This allows you to make any type of request using whatever URL or API keys you need. However it's important to note you also need to handle any errors or bad response codes.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. +1 for the console logging.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! How can we put the request into a function and wait for it in the router to send the request back, for cleaner code?

Comment: This is Deprecated