# Firebase Functions Get File

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a bunch of HTML files on my website (blogs). Instead of adding in the nav, header, footer, etc. I just want to call a function that will make a GET request to the HTML file and add in the header and footer. The issue with this is I can't find anywhere how I make a GET request to a file through a firebase function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions are essentially just tiny node scripts that run in response to external events, or an external HTTPS trigger. So you can just use the regular node ways of making a HTTP request, typically with the built in `http` module or the `request` library.

Some links:

- [HTTP GET Request in Node.js Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express)
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html