# CRUD operations with Google Cloud through Express.js

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to access many high resolution photos I have inside a Bucket in my Google Cloud account and serve them through Express.js.  I have the framework for the site already in place, just need to plug in the photos in the appropriate places.  How do I access my Bucket through the app I already have built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way would be to refer to the Cloud Storage Client Libraries. In your specific case, since your are using JS, you can refer to the [Node.js client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs). Notice that the documentation already includes examples as  to how to [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) and [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample) objects, as well as how to make many other operations with the bucket. For a full reference of the Client Library refer to this [link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/).

Another path you could explore is to use any package for making HTTP requests (find some examples on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express)), to make the relevant calls to the [XML](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) or the [JSON](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api) API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for my late response.  This is indeed the documentation I was looking for, but couldn't seem to find in the dense GCP docs by myself.