# Tying back OAuth user records to user profiles my end

Tags: facebook, oauth

Hopefully a quick one: Never implemented OAuth before and the client requires that once the user logs in (using facebook in this case) that this user is tied back to a record our end showing, for examples, which orders they have placed. I'm just trying to figure out the best way to do it.

Can anyone tell me if I can rely on the Facebook User ID from ever changing? Or point me in the direction of a decent article on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook user Id will always remain constant. To do something similar to what you want you would probably do this:

**Step 1 - Authenticate the User**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ - You would probably want to use the server side flow.

**Step 2 - Get Permissions**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ - You will need to have the user_about_me permission to get their UserId. You add this to your authentication link above by adding &scope=user_about_me

e.g. http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOURAPPID&scope=user_about_me&redirect_uri=LINKTOCOMEBACKTO

Please note your redirect_uri must be on the same domain as the settings in your app.

If you wanted to create an enhanced dialog box you can look at this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

**Step 3- Getting the userid**

If you are doing this inside a Facebook App then look at the userId in the SignedRequest.

Otherwise you use the Graph API. Here a StackOverflow question that shows how: [How to get the Facebook user id using the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546677/how-to-get-the-facebook-user-id-using-the-access-token)