# Facebook - Getting current user id with app access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook tab app, uses the FB.ui send dialog to send invitations to the user's friends to join and collaborate in my app.

[image]

Since the send dialog response is just a `{success:true}` JS Object, I can't tell who the recipients are.

By calling: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

I can get a valid access token, and can query public information of a specific user like so:

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?access_token=MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

---

**Q**:How can I get the current user id, without forcing a login ... is it possible?

Comment: You can not get user id without the user log in.

Comment: Please refer to this subject [How to get the Facebook user id using the access token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546677/how-to-get-the-facebook-user-id-using-the-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Page Tab App, you could access the `signed_request` as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/

Upon using the Share Dialog it's not possible AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however if a user did not approve your app the user info is just '"user":{"country":"uk","locale":"en_US","age":{"min":21}},' without the id

Comment: Signed request will only return a user ID if that user has logged into your app and granted it some permissions