# How to get userID from access token in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Token returned by `FBSDKGraphRequest`  is `10211282278486891`. How can I get the userID with token from `FBSDKGraphRequest`? My userID is `kukod.j`. How get it programmatically? How would Facebook forward after loading https://www.facebook.com/10211282278486891  in browser?

Checked [How to get the Facebook user id using the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546677/how-to-get-the-facebook-user-id-using-the-access-token) but it did not helped at all, it return token and not user ID.

Comment: Just make an API request for `/me` using the user access token ...

Comment: Value for "id" is the token and not the user id.

Comment: Your question title said you had an access token, and wanted to get the user id from there. _"My userID is kukoda.janos"_ - no, it is not, that is your profile "user name". And that that field has been removed with API v2.0 already.

Comment: So for profile user name I need to simulate opening it with browser?!

Comment: That would a) be against Facebook’s ToS, and b) you would not get an app-scoped user id belonging to your own app that way. // Why do you need this in the first place? For users that log in to your app, you will already get their ID that way - and users that did not log in to your app, are rather none of your app’s business to begin with ... so, what do you need this for?