# Codename One - Recognize the same user with GoogleConnect

Tags: codenameone

My question is about GoogleConnect (with Codename One), but maybe it can be valid also for FacebookConnect.

The problem is that the following code gives me a token that changes every time: using the same username and password of Gmail, I get a different token after every login. So... how can I recognize the same user?

```
String token = GoogleConnect.getInstance().getAccessToken().getToken();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I made the same mistake in recent materials. I need to update that code.

As explained here [How to get the Facebook user id using the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546677/how-to-get-the-facebook-user-id-using-the-access-token)

You need to fetch the user id using this query `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token="xxxxx"`  and that will be the unique id you can store.

Comment: And how to solve the same issue with Google inside a Codename One app? Here there are some instructions, but they need an external library and are suitable only on server side: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth At the moment I'm looking for a simpler approach.

Comment: I haven't updated code to the newer Google login and mostly used Google+ login back then so I'm not sure but see this https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get generally it says that `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` should return the profile Google has for you when the authentication token is in place

Comment: The informations here are very useful: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-2.html